# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList') while trying to get start animation

Tags: javascript, css-animations, intersection-observer

I am a beginner in javascript. Can you help me? The animation of the running string should start when the .stage container comes into the user's field of view. I see this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

So, when .stage container comes into the user's field of view, .string-animation class should be added to the .string class and animation should start. But nothing happens.

```
  
 (function () {
  var visualBlock = document.querySelector ('.stage');

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {    
    entries.forEach (entry => {
  var entryString = entry.target.querySelector ('.string');
  if (typeof getCurrentAnimationPreference === 'function' && !getCurrentAnimationPreference()) {
    return;
  }
  if (entry.isIntersecting) { 
    entryString.target.classList.add ('string-animation');
    return;
  }
  entryString.classList.remove ('string-animation');
});
  });

observer.observe (visualBlock);
})();
.stage {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 130px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 7px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #005490;
}

.running__string {
  display: block;
}

.string {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(111, 84, 84);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.string-animation {
  -webkit-animation: text 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: text 15s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: text 15s linear infinite;
  animation: text 15s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-350%, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-350%, 0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-350%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-350%, 0);
  }
}
<div class="stage">
            <div class="running__string">
                <div class="string">
                    <p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
 <script src="string.js"></string>
 </div>
```

Where had I gone wrong?

I tried adding a script tag to the desired container. I tried changing the class names, at first name of desired container and animation class was the same...

Comment: What is `entryString.target` supposed to be? Did you mean `entry.target`? What is unclear about the error message? You can’t read properties of `undefined`, but that’s what happens at `entryString.target.classList` because `entryString.target` is `undefined`; it’s trying to read `classList` off of `undefined` — not possible. If you don’t know why `entryString.target` is `undefined`, look at intermediate values: `console.log(entryString);`.

Comment: `entryString.target.classList` vs `entryString.classList` - which one is supposed to be correct?

Comment: Both, because the class will not be deleted when user's scroll to another place.

Comment: @Grebnik No. You’re doing `var entryString = entry.target.querySelector('.string');`, so `entryString` is either an [`HTMLDivElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) or `null`. An `HTMLDivElement` does not have a `target` property. So `entryString.target` will be `undefined`. But every `Element` has a `classList`, so `entryString.classList` will exist. It cannot be both.

Comment: Also, you have `<script src="string.js"></string>`, which is incorrect. [Validate your HTML](//validator.nu). Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately. Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212). Do this _before_ asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to remove the "target" property when adding animation, as I understood in this case it is inappropriate. Also added a wrap block. I apply the result and hope it will be useful to someone.

```js
(function () {
  const visualBlock = document.querySelector ('.stage');
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach (entry => {
      const entryString = entry.target.querySelector ('.string');
      if (typeof getCurrentAnimationPreference === 'function' && !getCurrentAnimationPreference()) {
        return;
      }
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entryString.classList.add('string-animation');
        return;
      }
      entryString.classList.remove('string-animation');
    });
  });

observer.observe (visualBlock);

})();
```

```css
.stage {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 130px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 7px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #005490;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
}

.string {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(111, 84, 84);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.string-animation {
  -webkit-animation: text 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: text 15s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: text 15s linear infinite;
  animation: text 15s linear infinite;
}
  
@-webkit-keyframes text {0% {transform: translate(0, 0);} 100%{transform: translate(-350%, 0);}}
@-moz-keyframes text {0% {transform: translate(0, 0);} 100%{transform: translate(-350%, 0);}}
@-o-keyframes text {0% {transform: translate(0, 0);} 100%{transform: translate(-350%, 0);}}
@keyframes text {0% {transform: translate(0, 0);} 100%{transform: translate(-350%, 0);}}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="string">
                        При заключении договора на бухгалтерское обслуживание консультация по вопросам оптимизации налогообложения - бесплатно!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script src="string.js"></script>      
            </div>
```